# JTable Row filtering by JTextField value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

I enter a name on my JTextfield , But my table don't filter any thing!

My code:

```
public class UserPage_Admin extends JFrame {

JTable table;
UserModel model;
public UserPage_Admin() {

    model = new UserModel(...);
    TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panelForm(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    RowFilter<UserModel, Object> rf = null;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterTF.getText(), 0);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(850, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` for a working example??? You've been given links to the tutorial many times before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are calling `RowFilter.regexFilter(filterTF.getText(), 0);` in `UserPage_Admin()`  constructor. How it supposed to read the **text** from the filterTF.  I think you should call it from an Action Event Listener assigned to a `JButton` which will be called upon submitting(clicking) the text as follows:

```
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = filterText.getText();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
          sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
          sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text, 0));
        }
      }
    });
```

If you want to use Filtering upon user key type event, add [key listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to the text field you are taking input filter-string.

```
filterTxtFeild.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keykeyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
              // on each key type event filter. 
             // put your filter code as submit button
            }
        });
```

However, as it is suggested in the comments below, to work with Swing Text Component, one should have used the [**`Document.addDocumentListener(DocumentListener)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#addDocumentListener%28javax.swing.event.DocumentListener%29). A Swing text component uses a [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) to represent its content. Document events occur when the content of a document changes in any way.  Add the document listener as follows:

```
filterTxtFeild.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // put your filter code here upon data insertion
      }

      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
      { 
            //put your filter code here upon data removal
      }

      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
    });
```

**Edit: Why DocumentListener is preferable ?**

If we want validation of input in the data source, using `KeyEvent` while filtering the data you’ll find it does not reflect the user’s keystroke and input events are sent to the listeners before they are processed by the data source. suppose that when we want an `user name` to be entered, someone input a text like `"$%^&"`. On such invalid input, `KeyEvent` will still be fired even though no valid changes has been made to data source. But, `DocumentListeners` are notified only when a valid changes has been made to the data source. Data entry components produce events in which a `validator` can listen for `asynchronously`, one should never [modify the contents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) of a text component from within a `DocumentListener`. If we do so, the program will likely deadlock.

Comment: Nice, But can you write a code that don't need to button, and when i enter a name, table should automatically filter it.

Comment: @Sajjad never to use KeyListener, nor for JTextComponent, starting with my question how KeyListener works with text inserted from System_ClipBoard

Comment: @mKorbel, i think you want to imply on using KeyBinding or DocumentListener right?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Use a DocumentListener.

Comment: No this is not a case for key bindings. Read the tutorial for a working example.

Comment: @camickr, I also prefer using DocumentListener, but for a pre-level swing learner should learn about key listener first. just my opinion

Comment: A KeyListener was used with AWT because there was no other choice. Swing has better API's which should be used. We spend half of our time on the forums answering questions because people find old code on the web that was designed for

Comment: :). I have seen advanced folks like you, HoverCraft, madProgrammer to advice OP about better things. I do think so. But sometimes i avoid it and let the user do whatever they are wanting. But yes they should ask 'whatever i am doing, is it the right way?'. Anyway i will try to follow you later on.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a KeyListener - that's **always** wrong for the use case here

Comment: To be truthful I didn't actually suggest it. he wanted to know how he could do, and i have written there.  I will update the answer asap

Comment: @kleopatra, I have updated the answer mentioning about all of your comment. But do you seriously think that for a pre-level learner, we should mention it? please don't get me wrong, i am not nagging about negative vote.

Comment: yes, I seriously think so: don't let them get into bad habits right from the start :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Why shouldn't use KeyListener in here? Just for that it is for `AWT`? Or because it has some defect? What is your mean about `text inserted from System_ClipBoard` ?

Comment: @Sajjad, i was going to write in the comment. but it wasn't allowing me, that is why wrote in the answer.

Comment: @kleopatra, I should be correct with the edited reply but if i am not, i will bring suggested changes.

Comment: @Sage I understand why you write answer, Thanks again.

Comment: @Sage Should `insertUpdate(...)` and `removeUpdate(...)` bodies be equal?

Comment: still there isn't something important from linked tutorial in my answer here, don't know, no idea for why reason you bothering with any code rather to push here link to tutorial, (btw here is maybe 100-500 similair questions with code in SSCCE form)

Comment: @mKobel, I am not bothering about writing a tutorial code here, i have already linked documentation and one tutorial page from java website. It is preferable to me writing a small portion of a code structure and marking the most important function so that they can move onto wheel instantly.

Comment: @Sajjad, yes, if you want to filter on partial word matching, why not?

Answer (score 1):

> I enter a name on my JTextfield , But my table don't filter any thing!

- there are two ways, you don't mentioned expected logics

  1. filtering on KeyTyped from DocumentListener (your code talking about ???)
  2. from ActionListener invoked from ENTER Key
- both a.m. ways added to JTextField

---

- then there are another two very important options

  1. filtering in whole JTables, columns and rows (your code talking about ???)
  2. in one (quite possible in two or more, never tried) columns

---

- everything depends of your goal
- everything by using standard methods implemented in API

Comment: Nice, I want filtering by key typing and filtering in whole table.

Comment: then easiest of ways is to follows  [code example - TableFilterDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java) from Oficial Oracle tutorial  [How to use Tables - Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Answer (score 0):

You simply fail to use *sorter* after initializing it. You should call *JTable.setRowSorter()*.

Comment: I add `table.setRowSorter(sorter);`, But not effected!

Comment: hmm -- downvoter care to explain? It's an obvious omission in the snippet provided by the OP and as such a good first catch.